# In Scala, what should be the type of a map from string to case class, and a map from string to functions taking those case classes as input parameter?

Tags: scala, types, deserialization, covariance, contravariance

The scenario I am trying to model is as follows. I have a couple of case classes that differ in their parameters, but they all extend the trait `Entity`.

```
// case classes 
trait Entity
case class E1(..params..) extends Entity
case class E2(..params..) extends Entity
...
case class En(..params..) extends Entity
```

I have a set of functions that take one parameter which is a subtype of `Entity`, like the following (we have more functions than entities):

```
// functions using case classes as parameters
def f1(val p:E1) = ???
def f2(val p:E4) = ???
...
def fm(val p:E2) = ???
```

Now, I get an instance of an `Entity` serialized into a String, and next to it I get the name of the function to call on it. To deserialize is not a problem: let's say I have a function `read[T](str)` that can deserialize `str` into an object of type `T`.

*I want to write a generic piece of Scala code, that given these two Strings (function name, serialized entity) can call the right function after deserializing the entity.*

I thought, I would need maps like below that given a function name will give me the function itself, and the type of its parameter. Then I should, in principle, easily be able to make a call as below.

```
// the mappings from String to entity and corresponding function
val map1 = Map (
    "f1" -> f1
    "f2" -> f2
    ...
    "fn" -> fn
  ) 
}
val map2 = Map (
    "f1" -> E1
    "f2" -> E4
    ...
    "fn" -> E2
  ) 
}

def makeTheCall (fname: String, ent: String) = map1.get(fname)(read[map2.get(fname)](ent))
```

1. This does not work because I cannot get the types right (and definitely the inferred types do not work either).
2. Is there a way to put `map1` and `map2` together (so that there is less chance of messing up the relations between the functions and parameter types)?

---

EDIT: For the sake of simplicity, we can here ignore the parameters to the Entities and therefore the actual serialized entity. This should help write a compilable code without too much work.

---

EDIT: Use-case: I am writing a program that receives messages from RabbitMQ. The body of the message contains the entity, and the message key implies what to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit 2*: Using a similar function as my previous edit, you could create a map with `String => Unit` functions which combine the deserialization and your function, so you don't need two maps.

```
def deserializeAnd[E <: Entity](f: E => Unit): String => Unit = 
  (s: String) => f(read[E](s))

val behaviour = Map(
  "key1" -> deserializeAnd(println(_: Foo)),
  "key2" -> deserializeAnd(println(_: Bar)),
  "key3" -> deserializeAnd((foo: Foo) => println(foo.copy(a=0))
)

def processMessage(key: String, serialized: String): Option[Unit] = 
  behaviour.get(key).map(f => f(serialized))

// throws an exception if 'behaviour' doesn't contain the key
def processMessage2(key: String, serialized: String): Unit =
  behaviour(key)(serialized)
```

---

*Edit*: It seems you have potentially multiple functions with the same input type, which makes it not a good use case for a type class.

You could use something like :

```
def makeTheCall[E <: Entity, Out](f: E => Out, s: String): Out = f(read[E](s))
```

It deserializes your string to the input type of the passed function.
Which you could use as `makeTheCall(f2, "serializedE4")`.

---

Even if you could find the right types to get your `makeTheCall` method working, you shouldn't use strings to differentiate between multiple types. What if you make a typo in `fname`,  `map1` contains `fname` and `map2` doesn't, ... ?

It is not really clear from your question what you want to do exactly, but it seems a type class would be a good fit for your case. With a type class you can create an instance with specific functionality for a type, which could do something like you want to do with your `f1`, `f2`, ... functions.

Imagine that your `f1`, `f2`, ... functions all return an `Int`, we could create a type class which contains such a function for `Entity` types :

```
trait EntityOperation[E <: Entity] {
  def func(e: E): Int 
}
```

Lets create some case classes which extend `Entity` :

```
trait Entity
case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int) extends Entity
case class Bar(c: String, d: String) extends Entity
```

Now We can create an instance of our type class for `Foo` and `Bar` :

```
implicit val FooEntityOp = new EntityOperation[Foo] {
  def func(foo: Foo) : Int = foo.a + foo.b
}

implicit val BarEntityOp = new EntityOperation[Bar] {
  def func(bar: Bar) : Int = bar.c.length + bar.d.length
}
```

We could use our type class as follows :

```
def callF[E <: Entity](e: E)(implicit op: EntityOperation[E]) = op.func(e)

callF(Foo(1, 2))          // Int = 3
callF(Bar("xx", "yyyy"))  // Int = 6
```

In your case this could look like :

```
def makeTheCall[E <: Entity](s: String)(implicit op: EntityOperation[E]) = 
  op.func(read[E](s))

// makeTheCall[Baz]("serializedBaz")
```

Comment: Type classes look like the correct solution to the orignal problem. However, since Mahdi mentions that there are more functions than argument types, resolving the correct `EntityOperation` using an implicit parameter won't work, right?

Comment: You are right, I missed that part. It would probably help a lot if Mahdi gave us some concrete examples of his f*n* functions

Comment: @PeterNeyens thanks for your answer. I added the use-case to the question. The `fn` functions do not return anything, but may send more messages, or update a database, etc. As you pointed out that my problem is not a good use-case for type classes, could you explain how your edit relates to the original answer?

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it possible to pass a key instead of the function (like in my previous edit).

Comment: @PeterNeyens Now I see what you mean by "It deserializes your string to the input type of the passed function." But unfortunately, when I put it into my code, I get a compile time error (maybe I missed some tiny detail while applying to my own code):

Error:(50, 29) No Manifest available for E.
    (s: String) => f(read[E](s))
                            ^

Comment: @PeterNeyens Actually, the other error message is more useful: Error:(62, 29) not enough arguments for method read: (implicit formats: net.liftweb.json.Formats, implicit mf: scala.reflect.Manifest[E])E.
Unspecified value parameter mf.
      val value: E = read[E](s)
                            ^

Comment: I do provide the format thing, but how do I add the manifest thing?

Comment: If you have already added an implicit parameter for `Formats`, just add another for `scala.reflection.ManiFest[E]`.

Comment: I changed it to the following, and there is no compile-time error. 
  def deserializeAnd[E <: Entity](f: E => Unit)(implicit mf: scala.reflect.Manifest[E]): String => Unit = {
    (s: String) => {
      implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
      f(read[E](s))
    }
  }

Comment: You can create an implicit parameter for formats too :  `def deserializeAnd[E <: Entity](f: E => Unit)(implicit formats: net.liftweb.json.Formats, mf: scala.reflect.Manifest[E]) ...`

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity I'm going to assume that none of your functions return a value, so each function is of type `something => Unit`. Furthermore, I'm not going to consider any exception handling, so I'm expecting the maps to always return a compatible value.

**Setup (as described in the question):**

```
trait Entity

case class E1() extends Entity

case class E2() extends Entity

case class En() extends Entity

def f1(p: E1) = println(25)

def f2(p: En) = println("foo")

def fm(p: E2) = println(p.toString)
```

We also have a function `read: String => Entity` that returns some subtype of `Entity`, and a storage (implemented as a `Map`) that stores our functions:

```
def read[T](s: String) = s match {
  case "E1" => E1()
  case "E2" => E2()
  case "En" => En()
}

val functionMap = Map[String, Nothing => Unit](
  "f1" -> f1 _,
  "f2" -> f2 _,
  "fm" -> fm _
)
```

The reason that the value-type of `functionMap` is a function from `Nothing` to `Unit` is, that, in order to call an arbitrary function from the map, the argument must be a subtype of all argument types. However, the only subtype of `E1` and `E2` is `Nothing`. This is also the reason why type inference didn't help you: There is statically no type that satisfies an arbitrary function from the map.

**A Solution:**

If you want to stick to the map there is no solution that gives you static safety. However, if you know what you are doing (or are handing exceptions at runtime), you can solve the problem doing a runtime cast. First, you deserialize your `Entity` using the read method. Then, you resolve the method you want to call by looking up `fName` in the function map. If you are sure that the function and the parameter match, then you can cast this function and make the compiler happy:

```
def makeCall(fName: String, ent: String) = {
  val param = read(ent)
  functionMap.get(fName).get.asInstanceOf[param.type => Unit](param)
}
```

Comment: The functionMap works, but how do I define the other map? In your answer, you define `read`, but the `read` function is actually from a JSON library that does the deserialization for me, and it needs to know the type of the object upon calling. So before making a call to `read` I need to determine the type of the output. That's why I need the other map as well. Or do you any way out of it?

Comment: I don't know if that is possible, since type information is static. The only reason the code I provided works is that I basically said "screw type safety" and told the resolved function what type it has to expect. I don't know if that will work for the JSON-library you are using. However, it seems you already found a solution, which basically makes the type-argument the other way around, specifying the deserialized type as being the same as whatever is in the map, which is a neat solution.